# Poll works on stdin when entering manually, but not when input is piped and not redirected

Tags: c, linux, shell, polling

Consider this C program:

```
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TIMEOUT 500 // 0.5 s
#define BUF_SIZE 512

int fd_can_read(int fd, int timeout) {
    struct pollfd pfd;

    pfd.fd = fd;
    pfd.events = POLLIN;

    if (poll(&pfd, 1, timeout)) {
        if (pfd.revents & POLLIN) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argv, char **argc) {
    int fd;
    size_t bytes_read;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];

    fd = STDIN_FILENO;

    while (1) {
        if (fd_can_read(fd, TIMEOUT)) {
            printf("Can read\n");
            bytes_read = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

            printf("Bytes read: %zu\n", bytes_read);
        }
        else {
            printf("Can't read\n");
        }
    }
}
```

It tries to poll given file descriptor (which is the fd of stdin in this case), and tries to read from it when it's available for reading. Here's an example input file called "input":

```
stuff to be read
```

So let's say I run the program, give a few inputs and close it:

```
./a.out
test
Can read
Bytes read: 5
Can't read
Can't read
...
```

So lets try reading the input from a file by piping/redirecting the contents of it to `stdin` of my program:

```
cat input | ./a.out # Or ./a.out < input
Bytes read: 0
Can read
Bytes read: 0
Can read
...
```

Now, the poll returns instantly (does not wait for the timeout to run out), and gives the results I was not expecting. I do know `poll()` does not work on files correctly, but if I'm not mistaken, I'm not reading from a file.

Comment: I suggest you [read a `poll` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), and pay some attention what it can return on an error, and think about if that is "true" or "false".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry, && was a typo.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude alright, so so if I'm not mistake, I should be using `if (poll(&pfd, 1, timeout) > 0)` instead of `if (poll(&pfd, 1, timeout))`, but now the problem persists with `./a.out < input`, but not with `cat input | a.out`

Comment: *the poll returns instantly (does not wait for the timeout to run out)* as it should. Why would you expect to see any other behaviour?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that [`poll`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (just like [`select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)) only tell you that a call to e.g. [`read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) will not block. It doesn't tell you if there's actually anything to read.

And if you read [the `read` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) you will see that when it returns `0` it means *end of file* (or connection closed for sockets).

What `poll` is telling you is that `read` can be called without blocking, and what `read` tells you by returning `0` is that there is nothing more to read.

You will get a similar "false positive" by pressing the end-of-file shortcut key (by default <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> on POSIX systems like Linux) for the non-piped or -redirected input example.